# Ansible Playbook - Can't pass variables between tasks in one play

Tags: ansible

I'm an Ansible AWX newbie.  I'm trying to pass a variable between two tasks in a playbook.  The playbook looks like this:

```
---
- name: start
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:

  - name: Check Debian disk space
    command: df --output=avail {{ a7_pcap_data_path }}
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
    register: df_output

  - name: Show Debian free space
    vars:
      a7_free_space_mb: "{{ (df_output.stdout_lines[1]|int / 1024)|round(0,'floor') }}"
      a7_spare_space_mb: "{{ a7_free_space_mb|int - (a7_capture_volume_mb|int * 1.1) }}" # Allow 10% for safety
    debug:
      msg: "Spare space: {{ a7_spare_space_mb }} MB"

  - name: Pass/fail check
    debug:
      msg: "Spare space: {{ a7_spare_space_mb }} MB"
```

The `a7_pcap_data_path`and `a7_capture_volume_mb` are passed in as AWX variables. When I run this from the Job Template in AWX, I get this:

```
Identity added: /tmp/awx_57_PesTa2/credential_3 (/tmp/awx_57_PesTa2/credential_3)
SSH password: 

PLAY [start] *******************************************************************

TASK [Check Debian disk space] *************************************************
changed: [ip-172-31-14-43.eu-west-1.compute.internal]

TASK [Show Debian free space] **************************************************

ok: [ip-172-31-14-43.eu-west-1.compute.internal] => {
    "msg": "Spare space: 3020.0 MB"
}

TASK [Pass/fail check] *********************************************************
fatal: [ip-172-31-14-43.eu-west-1.compute.internal]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'a7_spare_space_mb' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/var/lib/awx/projects/pre_checks/test.yml': line 21, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n  - name: Pass/fail check\n    ^ here\n"}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
ip-172-31-14-43.eu-west-1.compute.internal : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
The variable a7_spare_space_mb obviously is available in the task Show Debian free space but not in the subsequent task.
```

It appears that the scope of the a7_spare_space_mb variable is only within the task in which it's defined, but from what I've read, the scope should be the entire playbook.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks and regards...Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to use [set_fact](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/set_fact_module.html)

```
- set_fact:
    a7_free_space_mb: "{{ (df_output.stdout_lines[1]|int / 1024)|round(0,'floor') }}"
    a7_spare_space_mb: "{{ a7_free_space_mb|int - (a7_capture_volume_mb|int * 1.1) }}" # Allow 10% for safety

- name: Show Debian free space
  debug:
    msg: "Spare space: {{ a7_spare_space_mb }} MB"

- name: Pass/fail check
  debug:
    msg: "Spare space: {{ a7_spare_space_mb }} MB"
```